# Create a ListView with VerticalScroll and Rounded corners in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I have a listview that I fill with data from a xml file.
I want this list to have a scroll and round corners, when I fill it with more elements that it can show, the scroll appears automatically:

```
ListView x:Name="Scent_Edit" SelectionMode="Single" Height="283" Margin="0,7,0,0" SelectedIndex="{Binding CurrentDelete, Mode=OneWayToSource}" SelectedItem="{Binding ToDelete, Mode=OneWayToSource}" IsEnabled="{Binding EditEnabled}">             
        </ListView>
```

[image: Scroll, no round corners]

but if I add the code to have round corners the scroll never comes up:

```
ListView x:Name="Scent_Edit" SelectionMode="Single" Height="283" Margin="0,7,0,0" SelectedIndex="{Binding CurrentDelete, Mode=OneWayToSource}" SelectedItem="{Binding ToDelete, Mode=OneWayToSource}" IsEnabled="{Binding EditEnabled}">
            <ListView.Template>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Border CornerRadius="4" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black">
                        <ItemsPresenter></ItemsPresenter>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </ListView.Template>
        </ListView>
```

[image: No scroll, round corners]

Is there any way to have both, scroll and round corners on the listview?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ScrollViewer` is part of default template. `ItemsPresenter` is just `ItemsPanel` with all the items. It does not include `ScrollViewer`. If you change `Template`, and need scrolling, you need to add it manually

```xml
<ListView x:Name="Scent_Edit" ...>
   <ListView.Template>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">
         <Border CornerRadius="4" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black">
            <ScrollViewer>
               <ItemsPresenter/>
            </ScrollViewer>
         </Border>
      </ControlTemplate>
   </ListView.Template>
</ListView>
```